# Identity involving Stirling number of the second kind

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, special-functions, partitions, stirling-numbers

I'm looking for a citable reference for the following identity involving the Stirling numbers of the second kind $S(n, k)$ stated in [Equation (27)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html): For $n \geq 2$,
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n S(n, m) (-1)^m (m-1)! = 0.
$$
Thank you.

Comment: I would think that MO or MSE are "citable references". There are many, many proofs: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1279874/87355 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395139/combinatorial-proof-of-a-stirling-number-identity and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1125097/87355 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3255200/87355

Comment: You want to require $n \geq 2$.

Comment: This is Problem 3.13 (c) in [Ioan Tomescu, *Problems in Combinatorics and Graph Theory*, Wiley 1985](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=89E10D73E81E3F97C16E3AFB67833630).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first formula in Section 24.1.4.I.B in Handbook of mathematical functions with formulas, graphs, and mathematical tables, Dover edition, 1965 (Library of Congress Catalog Card Number: 65.12253) by Abramowitz and Stegun is
$$
x^n=\sum_{m=0}^n S(n,m) x(x-1)\cdots(x-m+1). \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Assuming here $n>1$ (so that $S(n,0)=0$), dividing both sides by $x$, and then letting $x=0$, we get the desired identity
$$\sum_{m=1}^n S(n,m)(-1)^m(m-1)!=0.$$

---

One may note that Riordan (An Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis, Wiley, 1958, formula (35) on p. 33) uses identity \eqref{1} to *define* the Stirling numbers $S(n,m)$, then deriving their combinatorial definition (as the number of ways of partitioning a set of $n$ elements into $m$ nonempty sets) -- cf. formula (38) on p. 33 and the third display from the bottom on p. 91 of the book.

Comment: You can also substitute $x=-1$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : Thank you for your comment. Then you will probably need some other identity as well, because on the right-hand side you will have $\sum_{m=1}^n S(n,m)(-1)^m m!$ rather than $\sum_{m=1}^n S(n,m)(-1)^m(m-1)!$ (also $(-1)^n$ instead of $0$ on the left).

Comment: Sorry for confusion, indeed this is a different identity!